# Receive an undefined value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Good afternoon, I'm having trouble making my data accept a value undefined
follows code:

```
interface IModalContatos {
  dados: IContatos;
  onSave(dados: IContatos): void;
  onClose(): void;
}
```

I am passing this data into my modal and it is returning the error to me
** Type 'IContacts | undefined 'is not assignable to type' ICContacts'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ICContacts'. **
follow my modal

```
<ModalContatos
          dados={contatoParaAtualizar}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onSave={(contatoAtualizado) => {
            handleClose();
            if (atualizandoIndex === null) {
              setListaContatos([...listaContatos, contatoAtualizado]);
            } else {
              listaContatos[atualizandoIndex] = contatoAtualizado;
              setListaContatos([...listaContatos]);
            }
          }}
        />
```

also below my const of the modal

```
const [contatoAtualizado, setContatoAtualizado] = useState<IContatos>(dados);
  useEffect(() => {
    setContatoAtualizado(dados);
  }, [dados]);
```

I believe that data accepting an undefined value will resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to add `undefined` type as follows :

```
interface IModalContatos {
  dados: IContatos | undefined;
  onSave:(dados: IContatos | undefined )=> void;
  onClose:()=> void;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand, i will check this question, but my doubt is how can i make my property dados accept IContatos and undefined value, thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome, do you mean `onSave:(dados: IContatos)` could accept  `IContatos` or undefined?

Comment: if yes try out `dados: IContatos | undefined;onSave:(dados: IContatos | undefined)=> void;`

Comment: my problem is actually not on onSave but in the data: IC contacts because this data must accept an undefined value also for my Type 'IContacts | undefined 'cannot be assigned to type' ICContacts'. The type 'undefined' cannot be assigned to the type 'ICContacts' that is happening on my property data = {contactParaUpdate} works correctly i send a image to

Comment: right, now it generated another error Argument of type 'IContacts | undefined 'is not assignable to parameter of type' IContacts [] | (() => ICContacts []) '. pleas check image bellow https://ibb.co/rbP8BGj

Comment: so try out `onSave:(dados: IContatos | undefined )=> void;`